# How do I embed an image at actual size?

Tags: images, media-library, wysiwyg

I'd like to give the user the option to insert images into posts, and have the image display at its actual size.

How do I do this?

Currently, if an image is selected from the media library, a dropdown menu displays, giving sizing options. None of the options allow for a default size.

Neither are there any options that allow for inline style to be turned off for the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under ATTACHMENT DISPLAY SETTINGS > Size > Select Full Size from the drop down menu.

Comment: This is not the case if the theme is using the `$content_width ` global, which many do, including all the default ones.

Comment: You can change them easily if needed http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width